# Passing data from mysql to modal using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can I pass data from my data base using php. I am using google marker to display my modal I used "addListener('click', function(event)" to show the marker. My problem is passing the data from my mysql database into my modal. 
I want to show all the data in my database for example. I want to display the ID column ($row['id']).

Modal Code:

```
<div class='modal'>
            <div class='modal-dialog'>
                <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                        <h3 class='modal-title'>Branch Details</h3>
                        <span class='modal-close'>
                            <i class='fa fa-close'></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-subheader'>
                        <a class='modal-subheader-tab subheader-active'>Summary Details</a>
                        <a class='modal-subheader-tab'>Sales Report</a>
                        <a class='modal-subheader-tab'>Detailed Sales Report</a>
                        <a class='modal-subheader-tab'>Gallery</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id='details' class='tab-content'>
                        <div class='details-row'>
                            <p class='left-details'>Branch ID:</p>
                            <span> <?php echo $row['id'];?></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

Marker code:

```
<?php
    require "connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<script>
            function initMap() {
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
                var uluru = {lat: 13, lng: 122};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 5.2,
                    center: uluru
                });";

                if ($count > 0){
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "
                        var content = '';
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        content:content,
                        position:{lat:{$row['latitude']}, lng:{$row['longitude']}},
                        map: map
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function(event) {
                    $('.modal').addClass('show');
                }.bind(marker));";
            }
        }     
echo "}


</script>"
?>
```

Comment: read up on AJAX - that is what you are asking here.  While you can use PHP to pull data when loading the HTML page, you have to use AJAX for updates.  In your code, it looks like you are somehow expecting a PHP page to add javascript - - - well, it is just odd looking.  Go learn AJAX - it is simple, once you get it.....

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, Please use and let me know the output

```
<?php
    require "connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLocation";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
        var uluru = {lat: 13, lng: 122};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5.2,
            center: uluru
        });

<?php if ($count > 0){ ?>
     var marker, i;
     <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     ?>
        var content = '';
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            content:content,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['latitude']?>, <?php echo $row['longitude'] ?>),
            map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function(event) {
                    $('.modal').addClass('show');
        }.bind(marker));
    <?php }
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: the code wont work. What I want sir, is the when I click a marker the data of that marker will be transferred/displayed on to my modal